# double free or corruption in the Stack destructor

Tags: c++, g++

I am pretty sure the problem is at `while (!empty()) pop();` because after I commented it out. everything works fine. but it doesn't `delete` `head`. what's wrong with this part?

The intention is as follows: LinkedList has two data members, `head` and `tail`. When the list is empty, these should both be equal to `0`. When the list is non-empty, then both `head` and `tail` shall be non-zero, and they should refer to the first and last items in the list respectively. And there shall be a path from `head` to `tail` via the `next_` pointers. If the list has only one item, then `head == tail`.

```
#include <iostream>
//stack using linked list
class LinkedList {
 public:
  LinkedList() : head(0), tail(0) {}
  ~LinkedList() {
    while (!empty()) pop();
    std::cout<< "~LinkedList" << std::endl;
  }
  void pop() {
    node* temp;
    temp = head;
    for ( ; temp->next_ != 0; temp = temp->next_) {
      tail = temp;
    } 
    delete temp; 
    tail->next_ = 0;
    std::cout << "pop()" << std::endl;
  } //removes, but does not return, the top element
  int top() {
    return tail->value_;
  } //returns, but does not remove, the top element
  bool empty() {
    return head == 0;
  }
  void push(const int& value) {
    node* element = new node(value);
    if (empty()) {
      head = tail = element;
    } else {
      tail->next_ = element;
      tail = element;
    }
  } //place a new top element
 private:
  class node {
   public:
    node(const int& input) : value_(input), next_(0) {};
    int value_; //store value
    node* next_; //link to the next element
  };
  node* head;
  node* tail;
};
int main() {
  LinkedList list;
  list.push(1);
  list.push(2);
  std::cout << list.top() << std::endl;
  list.pop();
  std::cout << list.top() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

fixed the problem by changing the destructor to the following codes:

```
  ~LinkedList() {
    while (head != tail) pop();
    delete head;
    std::cout<< "~LinkedList" << std::endl;
  }
```

Comment: just a note - when using a single linked list it is way easier and efficient to keep the top of the stack at head, not at tail.

Comment: Your `pop` function never changes `head`, but your  `empty` function only checks `head`. Something's wrong there.

Comment: @Mat eventually, `tail` and `head` would point to the place and `delete temp` is to free `head`, right?

Comment: What `head` points to does not change if you do not assign to `head`. `free` doesn't nullify the pointer you give it, and certainly not other pointers to the same location.

Comment: @ihm, I added a second paragraph to your question. Can you check it and confirm that I have described your intended data structure correctly?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid yes. that's what I like to have.

Comment: @Mat right, I am trying to fix this problem. any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

You have one part of your problem here

```
bool empty() {
    return head == 0;
}
```

When is `head` set to `0` (`NULL`)? Never?

Comment: Yes, but except for that. What happens in `while (!empty())`?

Comment: after `head` get deleted in `pop()`, `head` would point to 0. and `while(!empty())` would be `false`, right?

Comment: Well, no. `delete temp` doesn't set `head` to NULL (or `temp`, for that matter).

Comment: so after `delete temp` the last element, `head` and `tail` are gone. and `while(!empty())` goes into an infinite loop or a crash?

Answer (score 1):

`pop()` is wrong. When you have only one element left, both `head` and `tail` point to it. So when you `delete temp`, you are in fact deleting both `head` and `tail`, then you are:

- accessing `tail`, which is now a deallocated pointer, and
- not setting `tail` or `head` back to 0

Comment: I got what you mean. I am thinking how to fix this `pop()`. any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Your `pop()` doesn't fix `this->head` if you `pop()` the last element in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You could add these checks at the start. This is a boring solution, and perhaps you should change your overall design, but this code should correct your current algorithm for `pop`. In particular, when popping the last item, both head and tail should be set to zero.

Also, it should be `delete tail->next_;`, not `delete temp;`, just before the `tail->next_ = 0;`

```
  void pop() {
    if(head == 0) {
        // the list is empty, there's nothing to pop. This should be an error!
    }
    if((head != 0 && head == tail) {
        // there is only one item in the list
        delete head;
        head = 0;
        tail = 0;
    }
    node* temp;
    temp = head;
    for ( ; temp->next_ != 0; temp = temp->next_) {
      tail = temp;
    } 
    delete tail->next_; 
    tail->next_ = 0;
    std::cout << "pop()" << std::endl;
  }
```

I haven't tested this, but it should fix some of the problems.